# Is it impossible using stl under .net c++ managed code?

Tags: .net, c++, stl

It's clear that stl heavily depends on pointers. So does it means that there's no way using stl under c++ .net managed code?

Comment: Yes, that's right. I wonder is there any way using stl write managed code.

Answer (score 3):

You may take a look at the [following article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/mcpp/gcstl.aspx).

Comment: Wonderful article. It seems that I have to do a lot of homework before completely comprehending it, sigh...

Comment: Just note that this article is about old (and deprecated) Managed Extensions for C++, not C++/CLI.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2010 provides [STL/CLR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385954.aspx), which appears to be an extention of the STL that is compatible with .NET classes

Comment: Oh, that's great that Microsoft offered it. By the way, Visual Studio 2008 also contains the library.

Comment: I believe it was first added to VS 2005 as STL.NET